# SQL Stored Procedures Parameter Names Query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters

How does one query, or receive in any way, the parameters (including names of arguments) from a SQL Stored Procedure?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight Variation if you want to limit to a particular procedure and use system views in sql-server

```
SELECT *
FROM
    sys.parameters p
    INNER JOIN sys.procedures sp
    ON p.object_id = sp.object_id
    AND sp.name = 'ProceedureName'
```

OR Just use other

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = 'ProcName'
```